# Ant optional classpath element

Tags: ant, multi-project

I have some modules and a main runnable project. I have common build file, and

build.common.xml

```
<target name="build" >
  <path id="libraries.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
  </path>
  <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6">
    <classpath refid="libraries.classpath" />
    <classpath refid="modules.classpath" />
  </javac>
</target>
```

..and every module declares its own dependencies in their build.xml:

```
<path id="modules.classpath">
  <pathelement path="../ModuleA/${build.dir}" />
  ...
</path>
```

The problem is if there is no internal dependency I get the following exception:
"Reference modules.classpath not found."

What is the solution for that? **How could I declare an optional classpath element?**

**Note:** *If anybody want to suggest to create jars out of my modules, please justify this. I'm going to have 5-10 rapidly changing modules, and I don't want to do unnecesary steps in the build process.*

**Update:** I extracted the build into two different targets and created a condition for them, but did not help (it echoes the 'false' and builds with module-dependencies):

```
<target name="build">
    <condition property="modules.classpath.set" else="false">
          <isset property="modules.classpath"/>
    </condition>

    <echo message="modules.classpath is set: ${modules.classpath.set} " />
    <antcall target="build-with-modules" />
    <antcall target="build-without-modules" />
</target>

<target name="build-with-modules" if="modules.classpath.set">
    <echo message="Building with module-dependencies" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6">
        <classpath refid="libraries.classpath" />
        <classpath refid="modules.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="build-without-modules" unless="modules.classpath.set">
        <echo message="Building with  no dependent modules" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6">
        <classpath refid="libraries.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I know the problem: `<path id="modules.classpath">` is not a property, so the `<isset property="modules.classpath"/>` always became false. But I don't know the solution...

Comment: I've tried `<available classpathref="modules.classpath" property="modules.classpath.set" />` , but it does not work neither...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition [`isreference`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html):

> Test whether a given reference has been defined in this project and - optionally - is of an expected type.

So, try

```
<condition property="modules.classpath.set" else="false">
    <isreference refid="modules.classpath"/>
</condition>
```

Also on that page, there is a link to a page that describes custom conditions. If none of the provided conditions meets your requirement, then just write one.

Update:

The logic of `if` and `unless` in `<target>` is to check if the property has been set -- for `if`, the target runs when the property has been set; for `unless`, the target runs when the property has NOT been set -- not the value of the property.

I have never checked the code of the condition `isreference`, but I think maybe the `else="false"` should be removed.

If removing that part still doesn't help, then you may need to use some embedded groovy or beanshell script, or write your own condition.

Comment: Now the condition is good, but it always run the first target, even if its condition is false: `[echo] modules.classpath is set: false 
     [echo] Building with module-dependencies` I tried to echo the property inside the target and before calling the target with the same result... Tried with `ant` and `antcall` too

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's very misleading to name such a checker to `if` it should have been `ifexist` or just `check`. Additionally if it is just a nullcheck (existence-check), it should work for all kind of variable: file, path, fileset, dir, dirset, etc... But it doesn't...

Comment: The internal code should just be like: `String xxx = getProperty("property name"); if (xxx == null) {return;}`, so it just supports properties.